# Running a .NET 4.5 ASP.NET MVC web app on a .NET 4 server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

I've just downloaded and installed Visual Studio 11 Beta. I looks great and I was thinking about upgrading some of my website to ASP.NET MVC 4 and .NET 4.5. The question I have is if I can run such a website on a hosting plan that has only .NET 4 installed? Maybe by marking the necessary dependencies as "copy local"? I've search around, but as this beta is fresh from the oven, I couldn't find any helpful data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have problems with your hosting. Anyway as many will say using beta for production is not a good idea (although I had done it several times). My suggestion is to switch to some HyperV hosting and install all necessary frameworks there.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about upgrading any of my bigger sites. My 2-page personal site and maybe a few that are still in development. It's be more so I can be ready for .NET 4.5 when the final version comes out. I googled HyperV hostings and they are way out of my budget.

Comment: I've tried publishing a test site to my server via Web Deploy and it doesn't even publish. Might be the new Web Deploy 3. I also tried with FTP and the web app complains about the targetFramework="4.5" attribute. For now I'm just going to upgrade to ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta. I did however find that DiscountASP.NET has a free ASP.NET 4.5 hosting trial at http://labs.discountasp.net.

Comment: That's great, I will definitely try that

Comment: While it may not be a good idea on a big site, ASP.Net 4.5 Beta does include a "Go Live" license to build and deploy on production sites. Scott Gu reference (2nd paragraph) http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/02/19/asp-net-mvc-4-beta.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i had similar problem,i have visual studio 2012 and my host running for .net 4.0
but my site was .net 4.5
when uploaded and saw the site i got error.

i backed up program.
then went to

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework
```

there were 3 folder v3.5 v4.0 v4.5
then i created 2 back up folder one for 4.0 and other for 4.5
from each v4.0 and v4.5 copy these:

```
1-System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll

2-System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.xml

3-System.Data.Linq.dll

4-System.Data.Linq.xml
```

now that i had back ups did these:
1-change target framework to 4.0 from project options
2-copied above assemblies from folder v4.5 to v4.0

then build application 
everything went well.

good luck.

Comment: There's a much easier way of doing these. Just right click the dependency in the solution explorer, select properties and for each needed references set the Copy Local property to True. .NET applications first check the bin folder for referenced DLLs and the Copy Local property causes the compiler to put them exactly there - in the bin folder.